# How to check case select folder empty and case cancel select folder of input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, select, input, upload

i have a problem with input select folder.

```
<input id="myInput" type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple>
```

i have a input folder, i want how to check case if select empty folder or cancel select. actual 2 case alway return the same event.

[image]

I want check empty folder select or cancel select for get folder name and show or clear file selected